Define Return to Player for games of chances with variable bet
Let us consider a game with a fixed bet $B$ and a random variable win $W$ that depends on a multiplier:
$$
W\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}, \quad \omega\mapsto M(\omega)b
$$
where $M$ is another random variable (the multiplier) and $\Omega$ is the set of outcomes of the game.
In such a game, it is easy to find a precise theorical definition of the RTP (Return to Player), the percentage of the bet won by the players (on average). In fact, one could simply take the expected value of the random variable $M$, or equivalently, of $W/b$.
However, there are games (like Blackjack) where the original fixed bet may be increased mid-game, depending on the outcome of the experiment (e.g., doubling the bet in certain situations). In such cases, the final bet in a game, starting from a fixed "entry bet" $b$, becomes a random variable itself, called $B$, and things get more complicated. For simplicity, we can assume a fixed strategy, in the sense that we can associate to easy outcome $\omega$ the final bet value $B(\omega)$ in a predictable way (depending of course on the original bet $b$).
My question is: how should we approach the computation of the RTP in such cases? Is $E[W/B]$ still the right approach, or should we use $E[W] / E[B]$ instead? I believe one should find a value $R$ such that, given a large number of independent games $n$ with identical entry bets $b$, final bets $B_i$, and wins $W_i$, we have:
$$
R = E\left[\frac{W_1+\cdots + W_n}{B_1+\cdots + B_n}\right].
$$
Any insights or suggestions on this? On one side, I believe that $E[W/B]$ should be more reasonable, but on the other side, I believe I can consider a small case in which $E[W] / E[B]$ is more precise; unfortunately, I cannot see how either could be use, possibly via results like the central limit theorem, to approximate the previous fraction, which give us a natural way to "simulate" the RTP.

If $M$ is either $0$ or $2$ in a simple game where the player either loses the initial bet amount or gets the bet back plus the same amount again, then in a more complicated game, $M$ can take on more values including possibly negative values if the bet might be increased mid-game. You can then still find $\mathbb E[M]$.  If instead  $M$ is either $1$ or $-1$ in a simple game then in a more complicated game $M$ can take on more values including possibly values more negative than $-1$ and again look at $\mathbb E[M]$.  In such games the initial bet $b$ is just a scaling factor.
